# Center the left div vertical, while keeping the right div standard

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4, I am trying to use the feature: Vertical alignment found on webpage: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

I have read my code a few times but cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="pt-md-4  row justify-content-md-center">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    <div class="col align-items-center">
      <?php if($_POST){ if (isset($pin_sucess)){ ?>
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <h4 class="alert-heading">
          <?php echo $pin_sucess; ?>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <?php }} ?>
      <form name="timeclock" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="pin">Pin</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="pin" id="pin" class="form-control input-md" required="true">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo Token::generate();?>" />
          <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-2">
            <input type="submit" name="pin_submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7">
    Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
  </div>
</div>
```

There are 2 div's on the page, The one on the left contain's the time clock form, I want this to be centered between the div that is on the right.

I may want to correct the right DIV, if it does get to long, it would turn into a scrolled div on the right.

For example, if the right div is 2 inch long, then the left div would be about 1 inch down or so.

Comment: what exactly are you expecting please be precise

Comment: `There are 2 div's on the page, The one on the left contain's the time clock form, I want this to be centered between the div that is on the right.`

Your description is little bit confusing. Can you put a Jsfiddle/codepen live example here?

Comment: Here is a example of what I am trying to do: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#alignment

Comment: @user8776656 you need that form div at the center ? is this what are you trying to say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you need the form div (on the left) to be vertically-centered against the content div on the right (which can have variable content)... to do this, i just introduced `col align-self-center` to the div which housed the form

complete **working snippet** below:

```css
.higherDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.higherDiv>.higherDiv {
  border: 1px dashed lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="pt-md-4  row justify-content-md-center higherDiv">
  <!-- FORM DIV -->
  <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 higherDiv col align-self-center">
    <div class="col align-items-center">
      <?php if($_POST){ if (isset($pin_sucess)){ ?>
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <h4 class="alert-heading">
          <?php echo $pin_sucess; ?>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <?php }} ?>
      <form name="timeclock" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="pin">Pin</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="pin" id="pin" class="form-control input-md" required="true">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo Token::generate();?>" />
          <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-2">
            <input type="submit" name="pin_submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- VARIABLE CONTENT DIV -->
  <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 higherDiv">
    Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
    <br />
    <br /> Variable width content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.